# 403 Forbidden on local nginx when the root directory is changed

Tags: nginx

I have set a nginx, php, mysql and phpMyAdmin on my laptop (running Arch Linux). Everything was ok till I tried to move the root in my home directory.

Here is the nginx configuration file I'm using:

```
server {
    ############### General Settings ###################
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root   /home/me/Development;
    charset utf-8;

    ############## Document Root #####################
    location  / {
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        autoindex on;
    }

    ############## PHPMyAdmin #######################
    #location /phpmyadmin {
    #   rewrite ^/* /phpMyAdmin last;
    #}

    ############# Error redirection pages ################
    error_page  404               NGINX/html/404.html;
    error_page  500 502 503 504   NGINX/html/50x.html;

    ############## Proxy Settings for FastCGI PHP Server #####
    location ~ \.php$ {
         if ($request_uri ~* /phpmyadmin) {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        try_files  $uri =404;
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; (depending on your php-fpm socket configuration)
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi.conf;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

}
```

So I'm trying to make this "Development" folder - the folder where I will store all my php projects. And I want to keep phpMyAdmin in its default location. 
Now i get 403 Forbidden if i try to access phpMyAdmin or any php file on the new location - error message:

```
2016/05/20 14:11:46 [crit] 5292#5292: *3 stat() "/home/me/Development/test.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

It should do something with the linux groups and rights but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

It's selinux, google disabling that or configuring it to allow what you need to do. 
When your perms are set right and the logs show 'permission denied' it's selinux.

Answer (score 0):

You are using HTTP to get your page. Now HTTP is returning you the error code '403' which according to RFC 2616 means "The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated."

The two possible reason for this error code

```
Authentication was provided, but the authenticated user is not permitted to perform the requested operation.
The operation is forbidden to all users. For example, requests for a directory listing return code 403 when directory listing has been disabled.
```

Try to check your file permissions. There is the solution.

Comment: Yes, I thought the same but giving it a 777 rights didn't helped. Is it possible that my nginx configuration is wrong?

Comment: I have no idea about nginx. But i can see very very similar questions are asked by others also. This means either this is very common issue with nginx or some particular release has this issue. Better to check the nginx developer forum or send a mail to them. May be they will reply.

Comment: Yes, I found as well many issues like this with no answers. So far it is related with the nginx configuration. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: I also got the 403 error code and tried to configure the rights of the file with chmod 777. Still the same result. 
My problem was I started the nginx webserver with `sudo nginx` instead of starting it with my user and my rights. Just start the server with `nginx` without `sudo` and you should be fine. 
I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

check the owners and mode of the folder by using `ls -l` command if user is sudo then run this `sudo chown -R yourusername:yourusername Development` adn also run `sudo chmod -R 777 Development`

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this and no results. Still getting 403.

Comment: Big -1 from my side, DO NOT use 777 this will allow ALL USERS to read / write & access this folder, it also sends a red flag to anybody else that you have no idea how to set permissions securely.